# Sorting integers and strings in a single line code

Tags: python

So I have the following list which represents students and their grades:

```
a = [('Tim Jones', 58), ('Anna Smith', 64), ('Barry Thomas', 80), ('Tim Smith', 80), ('Yulia Smith', 66)]
```

I need to define a function to sort the students by their grades in descending order then surnames and lastly their forenames. With the following line of code it all works fine:

```
def sortStudents(a):
    return sorted(a, key=lambda x : (-x[1], x[0]))
```

But now I also need to make sure it works with grades as strings instead of integers and the above function fails the tests. I figured that the " - " is causing problems so I tried:

```
return (sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse=True))
```

but it reverses the whole lists and it's not working as intended, even though it passes the string test.

What I think I need to do is check if the grade is integer and if it is - execute the first version of the code, and if not - execute something else, which I still haven't figured out.

Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You are very close but you need to turn your score into an `int` and then you need to split and reverse your name:

```
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: (-int(x[1]), tuple(reversed(x[0].split()))))
[('Tim Smith', 80),
 ('Barry Thomas', 80),
 ('Yulia Smith', 66),
 ('Anna Smith', 64),
 ('Tim Jones', 58)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = [('Tim Jones', '58'), ('Anna Smith', '64'), ('Barry Thomas', '80'), ('Tim Smith', '80'), ('Yulia Smith', '66')]
>>> b = sorted(a, key=lambda x: (-int(x[1]), x[0]))
[('Barry Thomas', '80'), ('Tim Smith', '80'), ('Yulia Smith', '66'), ('Anna Smith', '64'), ('Tim Jones', '58')]
```

It works no matter the grades are `string`  or `integer`...

Comment: Doesn't quite address the second part surname then firstname.

Comment: Oh I see, my bad :D